# Active Merchant Paypal Recurring Pem Error Neither Pub Nor Priv Key

Tags: paypal, activemerchant, pem

I am trying to use ActiveMerchant to make a Paypal Recurring transaction call. I used the patch here:

http://blog.vuzit.com/2008/08/01/paypal-website-payments-pro-us-with-recurring-billing-and-activemerchant/

and I'm stuck on this here:

```
ActiveMerchant::Billing::PaypalGateway.pem_file = File.read('paypal_cert.pem')
```

I am fairly sure the pem file is correctly downloaded from paypal. The error I receive is:

```
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activemerchant-1.5.1/lib/active_merchant/lib/connection.rb:129:in `initialize': Neither PUB key nor PRIV key:: nested asn1 error (OpenSSL::PKey::RSAError)
 from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activemerchant-1.5.1/lib/active_merchant/lib/connection.rb:129:in `new'

from calling the commit method from line 49 of paypal_pro_recurring.
```

I simply have 2 files - paypal_pro_recurring.rb from the tutorial and paypalTest.rb which I wrote and simply requires all files and calls the function. I hope the error isn't something stupid like I must require from an environment file or something. Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

Does the PayPalGateway need a passphrase? Maybe you forgot that.

I got a similar error message (although in other Gateway) when I gave the wrong passphrase for the private keys.